# Spacemacs: How do I set a key in anaconda-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, anaconda-mode

I'm using the python-layer and am trying to set <kbd>M-r</kbd> to run `replace-string` while editing Python files. I've tried all of the options below from inside the function `dotspacemacs/user-config`. Help?

```
;; NONE OF THESE WORK!
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "M-r") 'replace-string)
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\M-r" 'replace-string)
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "M-r" 'replace-string)
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'python-mode "M-r" 'replace-string)
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'anaconda-mode "M-r" 'replace-string)
(defun my-python-mode-config ()
  "For use in `mode-hooks'."
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-r") `replace-string)
)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-config)
(add-hook 'anaconda-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-config)
(global-set-key "\M-r"  'replace-string)
```

Comment: +1 would like to see some clear information around this. The documentation coincides with your attempts which seems to just not work. For beginners like myself it is quite a barrier. http://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#binding-keys

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about how Spacemacs works, but the attempts with
`global-set-key` or `evil-insert-state-map` aren't supposed to work,
because the local keymaps take precedence!

I think it should work to set it in the `anaconda-mode-map`. So you
can modify the `my-python-mode-config` function to call `(define-key anaconda-mode-map (kbd "M-r") 'replace-string)` instead.

Although, instead of defining the key every single time you switch to
anaconda-mode, the premature optimizer in me would do it only once:

```
(eval-after-load 'anaconda-mode
    '(define-key anaconda-mode-map (kbd "M-r") 'replace-string))
```

Finally, I vaguely remember that Spacemacs uses `use-package`. If that's the
case you can add

```
:bind (:map anaconda-mode-map ("M-r" . replace-string))
```

to the `(use-package anaconda-mode)` form you must
have somewhere in your config.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through a similar ordeal trying to bind a key in ess-mode with spacemacs. Assuming you're using evil-mode, I think the following will work:

```
  (evil-define-key 'insert python-mode (kbd "M-r") 'replace-string)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-r") 'replace-string)`

You can also set it the spacemacs way:

`spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'python-mode "oo" 'replace-string`

and you can use it by `SPACE o o`.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work (you can see I tried that in the last line of my code). M-r is still bound to `anaconda-mode-find-references

Comment: Did you add the kbd function before M-r ?

Comment: Yup, I added that to my .spacemacs and restarted to no avail.